# wifi enabling in ubuntu 15.04

Tags: wireless, broadcom

I have recently installed ubuntu 15.04 dual boot with windows 10. but my wifi is not enabled in ubuntu...is there need to install wifi driver in ubuntu...or suggest me command to enable wifi..

```
shubham@shubham-HP-Notebook:~$ lspci -nnk|grep 0280 -A2
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:804a]
    Kernel driver in use: bcma-pci-bridge
shubham@shubham-HP-Notebook:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to add the result of this terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A2`